# Yii Framework - data undefined - Ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, undefined

I'm two days trying solve this, but I have no success.

I have a page _form.php for my identificacaoEmigrante.php model and a page _form.php for my filiacao.php model.
In identificacaoEmigrante model, I have fields like:

- IdEmigrante
- nome
- idConjuge
- nomeConjuge
- idFiliacao (FK)

and in filiacao model, I have fields like:

- idFiliacao (PK)
- nomeMae
- nomePai

From this, I wanna save the identificacaoEmigrante _form in $_SESSION variables for after get these values in other pages.

When I click on the button with label: "Adicionar nova filiacao", I wanna go to the filiacao _form and fill that form and
when I come back, I want that identificacaoEmigrante _form be filled with previously entered data. IE, I'm filling identificacaoEmigrante _form and filiacao don't exists yet, so, I need click on button "adicionar nova filiacao" and call filiacao _form through onClick of TbButton event and fill that fields. When I come back from the filiacao _form, I wanna that fields of identificacaoEmigrante _form be filled with the $_SESSION variables.

My identificacaoEmigrante _form.php:

```
<div class="form container">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'identificacao-emigrante-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idEmigrante'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'idEmigrante', array('id'=>'idE')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'idEmigrante'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nome'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'nome',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64, 'id'=>'nome')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nome'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dtNasc'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'dtNasc'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'dtNasc'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idConj'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'idConj',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'idConj'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nomeConj'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'nomeConj',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nomeConj'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idFiliacao'); ?>
    <?php
        if ($model->isNewRecord) {
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
                   'model' => $modelFiliacao,
                   'attribute' => 'idFiliacao', //'id' CAMPO A BUSCAR
                   'data' => CHtml::listData($modelFiliacao->findAll(), 'idFiliacao', 'nomePai', 'nomeMae'),
                   'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Selecione a Filiação',),
                   )); //listData($modelDESEJADO->findAll(), 'CAMPO A SER MODIFICADO', 'CAMPO A MOSTRAR NO COMBOBOX')
        } else if (!$model->isNewRecord) {

            $qry = "SELECT filiacao.idFiliacao, nomePai, nomeMae from filiacao, identificacaoEmigrante where filiacao.idFiliacao = identificacaoEmigrante.idFiliacao";

            $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qry)->queryAll();
            $data=CHtml::listData($result, 'idFiliacao', 'nomePai', 'nomeMae');

            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
                   'model' => $model,
                   'attribute' => 'idFiliacao', //'id' CAMPO A BUSCAR
                   'data' => CHtml::listData($modelFiliacao->findAll(), 'idFiliacao', 'nomePai', 'nomeMae'),
                   'htmlOptions' => array(
                                          'options' => $data,
                                          ),
                   ));
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        $this->widget(
              'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
              array(
                    'type' => 'primary',
                    'buttonType' => 'ajaxLink',
                    'label' => 'Adicionar nova Filiação',
                    'htmlOptions'=> array(
                        'onClick'=> 'saveSession()',
                    )
              ));
    ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'idFiliacao'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        $this->widget(
              'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
              array(
                    'type' => 'primary',
                    'buttonType' => 'submit',
                    'label' => 'OK',
                    )
              );
    ?>
</div>
</div>
    <?php
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div><!-- form -->
```

My siteController.php:

```
...
public function actionMyActionName() {
    Yii::app()->session['idE'] = $_POST['idE'];
    echo json_encode(array("ide"=>$_POST['idE']));
}
...
```

My Javascript (a.js) code:

```
function saveSession() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: "/museu_emigracao/index.php?r=site/savesession",
    url: '/museu_emigracao/index.php?r=site/myActionName',
    data: {
        idE : $("#idE").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.idE);
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert(data + 'erro');
    },
    dataType: null
});}
```

I've tested dataType: JSON and others like "text", but my code doesn't return nothing, therefore a null value should be correct.

the data.idE return **undefined**, but in chrome's debug, it appears with the value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's letter-case issue use

```
console.log(data.ide);
```

Or

```
echo json_encode(array("idE"=>$_POST['idE']));
```

And change `dataType: null` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but nothing is changed.

Still undefined value is shown.

Comment: change dataType: null to dataType: 'json'

Comment: It enters on error function.
This should be null, I believe, because I don't return anything.